# How does isNaN verify the value of Prompt returning only string in this code?

Tags: javascript, prompt

As far as I know, Prompt returns only String type of value. Then, how does the below code work properly?

```
var a = prompt('Number or String? Verify now!');

if(!isNaN(a)){
  alert('This is number.');
}
else alert('This is string.')
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp, ***The global isNaN() function, converts the tested value to a Number, then tests it.***

> The isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number (Not-a-Number).
>
> This function returns true if the value equates to NaN. Otherwise it returns false.
>
> This function is different from the Number specific Number.isNaN() method.
>
> The global isNaN() function, converts the tested value to a Number, then tests it.
>
> Number.isNaN() does not convert the values to a Number, and will not return true for any value that is not of the type Number.

Answer (score 0):

isFinite(value) converts its argument to a number and returns true if it’s a regular number, not NaN/Infinity/-Infinity:

```
 alert( isFinite("15") ); // true
alert( isFinite("str") ); // false, because a special value: NaN
```

Sometimes isFinite is used to validate whether a string value is a regular number so check this code

var a = prompt('Number or String? Verify now!');

```
if(isFinite(a)){
  alert('This is number.');
}
else alert('This is not number.')
```